# Joining threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

`(Thread) A.join()` - causes current thread to wait for the thread A to complete.
I supposed then that calling `this.join()` from the run method will cause thread to deadlock - that it will wait for itself to complete. However it doesn't happen - code compiles and runs just fine - without deadlock. What happens when I call `this.join()` then?

Comment: Can you provide your code, please? According to the Java documentation and several other questions on here, a thread that calls `join()` on itself should hang indefinately.

Comment: I don't see how this is possible. If you look at the source for Thread.java on grepcode (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.join%28long%29), you'll see that it spins in a while (isAlive()) {wait();} loop, where isAlive is a native method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP uses this.join() in the provided example

Nathan in his example uses Thread.currentThread().join() instead.

By using this.join() a new thread is created which is getting joined, but the main thread is intact.

@Nathan
The following works as intended:

```
public class Main extends Thread {

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
       super.run();
       try {
           this.join();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().start();
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried creating a thread and using this.join, it still deadlocks for me. I don't know what the OP is doing to get her result.

Comment: +1 - @Pitelk's explanation holds water.  (And the down-voter is incorrect.)

Comment: but this.join() in the start method should block forever, should it not?

Comment: here putting join in the start method is the difference. putting this.join in the run method blocks. in start it doesn't block because the thread running the start method is different from the thread being started.

Comment: Oh; yes that would be correct! join() blocks only after the thread has started...

Comment: Nathan is correct! I overridden start() by mistake. Indeed if you put this code in run .. that thread will deadlock (but this thread, not the main). In the original post it is claimed that "it runs fine" which i believe is true because the main thread indeed runs fine

Answer (score 1):

That's not what my example does. This code joins on the current thread, causing it to deadlock:

```
public class ThreadJoinTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println("joining");
    Thread.currentThread().join();
    System.out.println("i'm back"); // we never get to this point
  }
}
```

You could try adding

```
System.out.println("current thread name=" + Thread.currentThread().getName() );
```

to your code to verify that the current thread is what you think it is.

Comment: Yes, but this is subtly different to the OP's description of the case that is not deadlocking.